# How to define a generic implementation of class and struct?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, .net-3.5

In a c# project, I have two classes: `SensA` and `SensB`.

```
SensA sensor_a = new SensA();
SensB sensor_b = new SensB();

structA data_a = sensor_a.getData();
structB data_b = sensor_b.getData();
```

I need something like this:

```
GenericSens genericSensor_a = new SensA();
GenericSens genericSensor_b = new SensB();

structA data_generic_a = genericSensor_a.getData();
structB data_generic_b = genericSensor_b.getData();
```

where `structA` is different from `structB`.

I would like to define a `GenericSens` (class/interface/whatever...) that implement the same method name, but returns a different data type depending on how I create it.

Is this possible?

Comment: Well that just sounds like you want a `Sensor<T>` class with a `Data` property (not a method named as if it were written in Java) of type `T`. What have you tried so far? What happened when you tried it? How much do you know about generics?

Comment: Are you wanting to use GenericSens polymorphically or just more as a base class because the behaviour for different sensors is largely the same? I'm fairly certain that you can't declare a method or property to return a different datatype in the specific SensA and SensB classes so you'd either need to have getData() or Data return object or some other base class that structA and structB both inherit from.

Comment: It's possible (in programming, practically anything is possible given enough effort, though not all things are good ideas :) ). But without specific details about your types (`SensA`, `SensB`, `structA`, `structB`) it's not possible to suggest what the right approach would be here.